# Creating a csv file in haskell

Tags: csv, haskell

I suspect this a bit of a noobie question...

So I have a list `myList` that I would like to write to a csv file, using the cassava library:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Csv

main = BL.writeFile "myFileLocation" (encode $ V.fromList myList)
```

as far as I can establish, encode has type `ToRecord a => Vector a -> ByteString` yet I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
                with actual type `V.Vector (a,b,c,d)'
    In the return type of a call of `V.fromList'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `V.fromList myList'
    In the second argument of `BL.writeFile', namely
      `(encode $ V.fromList myList)'
```

I'm confused!

Comment: What is the type of `mylist`?

Comment: Also, [`encode`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.4.2.1/docs/Data-Csv.html#v:encode) has the type `ToRecord a => [a] -> ByteString`, not `Vector a -> ByteString`.  What version of cassava are you looking at?  They switched from `Vector`s to lists in version 0.3

Comment: it's the latest version. Thanks for spotting the incorrect type signature, I have updated the main question. myList is a tuple in my problem domain: `myList :: [(Int,Int,Float)]`

Comment: As my second comment suggests, you're looking at the wrong version of the documentation.  You don't need to use `Data.Vector` at all, just use `encode myList` instead of `encode $ V.fromList myList`.